# java null pointer exception when trying to get path of an image

Tags: android

I am working on a contact list application and i am getting an error when i try to get the path of my image in my edit text:

```
12-27 18:12:37.909: E/AndroidRuntime(2620): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 18:12:37.909: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at org.example.dbcontactconsole.ContactDetails.onCreate(ContactDetails.java:54)
12-27 18:12:37.909: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-27 18:12:37.909: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

ContactDetails.java source is:

```
package org.example.dbcontactconsole;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;                                                                            
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ContactDetails extends Activity{
    private Button cancelButton;
    private Button saveContactButton;
    private static EditText poza;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private static EditText nameField; 
    private static EditText mobilePhoneField;
    private static EditText emailField;
    private static Uri currImageURI;

    private static String operationType;
    static final int RESULT_MODIFY_USER = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contactdetails);
         Button sButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         sButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View arg0) {
                  // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
                  // select a file
                  Intent intent = new Intent();
                  intent.setType("image/*");
                  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                          "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
              }
          });
        Bundle incomingActionType = getIntent().getExtras();
        operationType = incomingActionType.getString("mod_type");

        if (operationType.equals("addPerson")){

            nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactName); 
            mobilePhoneField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactmobile);
            emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactemail);
            poza=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            poza.setText(currImageURI.toString());
        }

        else if (operationType.equals("modifyPerson")){

            String modifyFirstName = incomingActionType.getString("cFirstName");
            nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            nameField.setText(modifyFirstName);


            String modifyPhoneNumber = incomingActionType.getString("cMobilePhone");
            mobilePhoneField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactmobile);
            mobilePhoneField.setText(modifyPhoneNumber);

            String modifyEmail = incomingActionType.getString("cEmail");
            emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactemail);
            emailField.setText(modifyEmail);    
        }


    cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelcontactbutton);
    saveContactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savecontactbutton);

    saveContactButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            Bundle contactData = new Bundle();

                if (nameField.getText().toString().length() == 0){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(ContactDetails.this).setTitle("Error").setMessage("First name field cannot be empty!").setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
                } else if (mobilePhoneField.getText().toString().length() == 0){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(ContactDetails.this).setTitle("Error").setMessage("Mobile Phone field cannot be empty!").setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
                } else if (emailField.getText().toString().length() == 0){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(ContactDetails.this).setTitle("Error").setMessage("Email field cannot be empty!").setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
                } else{
                    contactData.putString("contactFirstName", nameField.getText().toString());
                    contactData.putString("contactMobilePhone", mobilePhoneField.getText().toString());
                    contactData.putString("contactEmail", emailField.getText().toString());

                    resultIntent.putExtra("contactData", contactData);

                    if (operationType.equals("addPerson")){
                        setResult(RESULT_FIRST_USER, resultIntent);
                    }else if (operationType.equals("modifyPerson")){
                        setResult(RESULT_MODIFY_USER, resultIntent);
                    }               
                    finish();
                }
        }
    });

    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, resultIntent);
            finish();


        }
    });

    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               if (requestCode == 1) {
                   // currImageURI is the global variable I'm using to hold the content:// URI of the image
                    currImageURI = data.getData();
                   getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI);

               }
             }
           }


        public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri currImageURI) {
           // can post image
           String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
           Cursor cursor = managedQuery( currImageURI,
                   proj, // Which columns to return
                   null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                   null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                   null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
           int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
           cursor.moveToFirst();


              poza=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
               poza.setText(currImageURI.toString());
              return cursor.getString(column_index);

        }
  }
```

line 54 is:`poza.setText(currImageURI.toString());`
I think that the error appears because currimageURI has no value, but i made the onActivityResult method.  Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You wrote the `onActivityResult` method, so what? That method is called (if called) after the `onCreate` so `currImageURI` is null when `onCreate` gets executed.

Just do not do that in `onCreate`. Do it when `currImageURI` is not null, i.e. in the `onActivityResult` method.

Answer (score 0):

In your method `onActivityResult(...)` you redeclare the variable `currImageURI` as local variable and thus hide the field:

```
Uri currImageURI = data.getData(); // hiding the field currImageURI
```

Instead you should have

```
currImageURI = data.getData(); // now it's fine
```

Comment: @iancoslovak It's given in the answer.

Comment: He wants you to write the whole class with the answer there. @iancoslovak Christmas was two days ago... we can't give more gifts.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{  
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
       {
           if (requestCode == 1) 
           {
               // currImageURI is the global variable I'm using to hold the content:// URI of the image
               //Uri currImageURI = data.getData(); Replace this as follows
               currImageURI = data.getData();
               getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI);

           }
         }
       }
```

You're redeclaring the variable `currImageURI` twice in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: The problem of `NullPointerException` which was being thrown as you say should be solved by this change. If it is still not then you shouldn't have coded your application well and you need to trace carefully.